# firebase fcm push notifications in wordpress does not appear for the sender

Tags: wordpress, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

the user who sends the notification (PHP cURL) in a list of "registration_ids" tokens, does not receive the notification itself. (doubt if there is a rule that prevents the user from receiving the notification sent to himself).

the message is sent to all other users except the sender...

Is there any specific rule that prohibits it?

I tested it with other devices and it arrives normally to all registered tokens, except for the sender logged in the token. This problem does not occur when I test on localhost, only on prod with wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

## Sorted out

Problem reason: Deprecated version (used 7.15.0);

Resolution: I switched to compat version 9.15.0.